# How to query tree table structure which has no subnodes

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have data organized as a tree in Oracle 11g.

```
CREATE TABLE FOLDER
(
  NAME VARCHAR2(20),
  ID NUMBER(10, 0),
  PARENT_ID NUMBER(10, 0)
}
```

(I think this structure is obvious and I should explain it).

Trying to query only data that has no subfolders. Using this query (not sure its correct):

```
SELECT * FROM folder f WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
   SELECT *
    FROM folder cf
    WHERE f.id= cf.parent)
```

Is there possibility to use more optimal query for this purpose, for example using COUNT ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [hierarchical query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries003.htm):

```
select name, id, parent_id from (
  select name, id, parent_id, connect_by_isleaf as isleaf
  from folder
  start with parent_id = parent_id -- from comments
  connect by nocycle parent_id = prior id
)
where isleaf = 1;
```

The inner query gets the hierarchy plus a flag set using the [`connect_by_isleaf` pseudocolumn](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns001.htm#SQLRF50940):

> The `CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF` pseudocolumn returns 1 if the current row is a leaf of the tree defined by the CONNECT BY condition. Otherwise it returns 0. This information indicates whether a given row can be further expanded to show more of the hierarchy.

You need the `nocycle` parameter because the fact you have the parent ID set to the same as the ID in the top-level row of the hierarchy means the `prior` condition is met by that row itself, causing a loop. The combination of the starting condition and the `nocycle` will let this work.

Essentially that gives you the whole of the original table plus an extra column with a 1 or a 0. You can run that inner query on its own to see what it produces.

You're only looking for the lead nodes, this which have no sub-folders, so the outer query then filters on the generated `isleaf` column, so you only see those which are leaves.

Comment: select name, id, parent_id , connect_by_isleaf as isleaf  from folder start with parent_id is null  connect by parent_id = prior id - return no result

Comment: when I try to do this: select name, id, parent_id , connect_by_isleaf as isleaf from folder start with parent_id = 160177 connect by parent_id = prior id - I get ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data
01436. 00000 -  "CONNECT BY loop in user data"

Comment: I've added the `nocycle` parameter. You might want to check why you have a loop though. I can't tell without seeing your data, obviously. Maybe do some testing with `connect_by_iscycle` to see if there is something you don't expect in the data. What do the top level records have as parent, if it isn't null?

Comment: in top level parent_id = id

Comment: Well there's your loop... maybe then `start with parent_id = id` and include `nocycle`.

Comment: instead of nocycle is it a good way to use this: connect by   parent_id = prior id and  parent_id != id  ?

Comment: @user1491537 - I guess that would work in this specific case, as long as you don't have other loops (and I don't think you can with this structure); but `nocycle` is more generic.